# openCV and python: Morphological transformation outside boundaries

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using python and OpenCV.
I have a (rectangle or anything) kernel and trying to perform some morphological transformations. My question is what about image boundaries?

For example, how does openCV decide in kernel's elements outside boundaries for dilation? Does it ignore them or use its neighbor's value?

Comment: As far as I know, it ignores it, same way as a 2D kernel. Do you have a working code that shows a example ?

Comment: It automatically creates a border. If not specified differently is BORDER_CONSTANT with value depending on the morphological operation. I'll post a complete answer later if nobody does it before.

Comment: @Miki Can you post the complete answer today please?

Comment: @CristianoAraujo It's from the OpenCV tutorial the code. You can find it here `http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html?highlight=morphological`

Comment: @zinon please let me know if my answer is ok, or if you need additional info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As reported by OpenCV documentation for [morphologyEx](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=morphologyex#morphologyex):

> C++: void morphologyEx(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int op, InputArray kernel, Point anchor=Point(-1,-1), int iterations=1, int borderType=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue=morphologyDefaultBorderValue() )
>
> Python: cv2.morphologyEx(src, op, kernel[, dst[, anchor[, iterations[, borderType[, borderValue]]]]]) → dst

You see that the function by default create a border with a constant value. This value depends on the type of morphological operation and is defined by `morphologyDefaultBorderValue()`:

```
//! returns "magic" border value for erosion and dilation. 
//! It is automatically transformed to Scalar::all(-DBL_MAX) for dilation.
static inline Scalar morphologyDefaultBorderValue() { return Scalar::all(DBL_MAX); }
```

which will be then corrected for the actual matrix type. So, for `CV_8U` matrix the border values are either 0 (for *dilate*) or 255 (for *erosion*).

Note that all others morphological operations are different sequences of *dilate* and *erode*.

The border length is defined in the `FilterEngine` that actually performs the morphological operation as:

```
 int borderLength = std::max(ksize.width - 1, 1);
```

where `ksize` is the size of the structuring element.

So, by default OpenCV creates the additional boundaries needed (of the correct `borderLength` according to the kernel), with a specific value. This value guarantees that the morphological operation is consistent across boundaries.

Comment: Actually my question is about images' values outside the boundaries in conjunction with the kernel. Does the kernel ignore values of images outside boundaries or duplicate boundaries values to cover the kernel?

Comment: @zinon by default, there's no _duplicate_ boundaries, but  OpenCV _creates_ the additional boundaries needed (of the correct `borderLength` according to the kernel), with a _specific value_. This value guarantees that the morphological operation is consistent across boundaries. Clearer?

Comment: Yes, that's clearer. But these boundaries what values do the have?

Comment: @zinon, by default the value returned by `morphologyDefaultBorderValue`, which is basically `+Infinite` for all morphological operations, except for _dilate_, where the value is converted later in `-Infinite`.

Comment: Thank you! So, Let's suppose that BW image have intensity values 0 or 255, so for example for dilation the image outside boundaries has values 0 and for any other operation 255?

Comment: @zinon, Take care that I express myself poorly. It's `+Infinite` for erosion, and `-Infinite` for dilation. More complex morph operation such as  open, close, etc can be defined as a sequence of erosion and dilation. So YES, for CV_8U images the values for `+Inf` is actually 255, and for `-Inf` is actually 0.

Comment: OK, thank you very much!! Please put your comments in your answer and I will accept it!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!